# NPM Install through spawn does not install everything

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm building a release script in node. One of the steps is to clear out the `node_modules` and re-running `npm install`. This script:

```
spawn('npm', ['install'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

Starts installing the modules, and it successfully quits. But, not everything inside the `package.json` is installed.

Why is that?

Comment: It would help if you gave an example or two of packages that are not being installed. Also, what output does the spawned process produce?